# in Powershell ISE no output is displayed

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

```
Function Add ($x, $y)
{
    $Ans = $x + $y
    Write-Host “The Answer is $Ans”
}
```

is entered and saved as Add.ps1.  When add 4 5 is executed, this is the result:

```
PS C:\Users\ddahlenburg\PowerShell> add 4 5
```

If the same code is entered in the command window the output is produced.
What's up?

Comment: In ISE have you run ( arrow button! ) the script before call the function ???

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the script as follows - 
(Assuming that the script is saved at "C:\Users\ddahlenburg\PowerShell")

PS C:\Users\ddahlenburg\PowerShell> ./Add.ps1 4 5